# Convention for including executable in gem, both Unix and Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing a gem intended to be used on both Unix-type platforms and Windows and that includes an executable.  How should the executable be named?  Under Unix-type platforms it would normally have the form `someprog` and contain a shebang "#!/usr/bin/env ruby"; under Windows it would normally have the form `someprog.rb`, and rely on a file association of the ".rb" extension with Ruby.  But for a gem that is meant for both platforms, what is the proper way of handling it?

Comment: Since in *nix system the presence of any extension or no extension at all has no bearing the execution properties of the file itself why not make it a `.rb` file so that it works on windows through file association and works on *nix systems based strictly on execution rights.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but it seems unnatural - that would *require* that that the user type in "someprog.rb", and that seems unnatural in a POSIX-type environment where one typically invokes *name* without knowing, or **caring**, whether *name* is a binary executable, a script, or a tcl/perl/python/ruby/&c program.

Comment: No, it doesn't require the user to add the extension if you provide an alias or link to your command. That alias or link would be what is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I don't have a problem after all - I can simply use the Unix convention of naming the executable `someprog` with a shebang* and without an extension and it will work on both Unix-type and Windows platforms.  Apparently, the gem installation process results in a "facilitator" script being installed that calls the actual script under both types of OS's.

*Presumably, I don't even need the shebang under Unix, but I like to have it anyway.